# Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth not loggin in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am trying to log in with more than one auth guard but only the default is working.

This is my code.

**Guards**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins'
    ]
],
```

**Providers**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

**Authenticate Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/foo', function(){
    if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => 'bale@mail.com', 'password' => 'gareth'])){
        return redirect('/');
    }else{
        return 'No!';
    }
});

Route::get('/bar', function(){
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => 'lionel@mail.com', 'password' => 'password'])){
        return redirect('/');
    }else{
        return 'No!';
    }
});
```

Both routes return true when the **attempt** method is called but only the **web** guard actually logs a user in but if i switch the default guard to admin, the admin guard works and the web guard doesn't.

Can someone help me in solving this?

Comment: did you also made the `provider` to use the `Admin:class` model? also how the auth middleware looks like?

Comment: You can check again

Comment: You need to put them in separate middleware group to check which user is logged in as which role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a github repo that solved my problem.
https://github.com/gregoryduckworth/laravel-multi-auth